# Actionscript 3 setInterval stops after 10. (Audio)

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, setinterval

I have little problem with my script. Here is the code. http://pastie.org/2361140

When I set setInterval to something like 10 seconds, sound stops in about 10 calls to reset. But when its something like 20 mins it stops in first reset call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a timer dude.  I don't know if setInterval is something that is really used nowadays.

Comment: I made it with timer, but still sound stops.